# Select elements in such a way that most of the elements are in the beginning of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of values and I want to select `n` values in such a way that most of the elements come from the beginning of the list and diminish as it goes further in the list (as shown in the link below).

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = pd.Series(range(100))
np.random.shuffle(a)
a.values

array([26, 86,  2, 55, 75, 93, 16, 73, 54, 95, 53, 92, 78, 13,  7, 30, 22,
       24, 33,  8, 43, 62,  3, 71, 45, 48,  6, 99, 82, 76, 60, 80, 90, 68,
       51, 27, 18, 56, 63, 74,  1, 61, 42, 41,  4, 15, 17, 40, 38,  5, 91,
       59,  0, 34, 28, 50, 11, 35, 23, 52, 10, 31, 66, 57, 79, 85, 32, 84,
       14, 89, 19, 29, 49, 97, 98, 69, 20, 94, 72, 77, 25, 37, 81, 46, 39,
       65, 58, 12, 88, 70, 87, 36, 21, 83,  9, 96, 67, 64, 47, 44])
```

what is the good way to select those numbers?

http://www.bydatabedriven.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screen-Shot-2012-12-03-at-8.12.36-PM.png

As an example if n = 10, then the returned values may be (more numbers picked from the begining of the list as compared to those values which are to the end of the list) :

26, 2, 16, 92, 8, 45, 61, 99, 94 39

Comment: I don't really understand your requirements.

Comment: The definition of your "curve" -- or the effect of position in the input list (is the first element five times more likely to appear than the last?  ten times?) -- would be necessary to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and pass appropriately-shaped weights, either directly or using [`pd.Series.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) since you're using pandas.  For example:

```
In [59]: s = pd.Series(range(100))

In [60]: chosen = s.sample(10**6, replace=True, weights=1.0/(1+np.arange(len(s)))) #typecast the weight to float

In [61]: chosen.hist(bins=50).get_figure().savefig("out.png")
```

gives me

[image: sample histogram]

You can tweak the weights function to your heart's content.  Here I used basically 1/i, so that the 4th element is 4 times less likely to be selected than the first.  You could take that expression to some power, with `**2` making the 4th element 16 times less likely to be selected, or `**0.5` making the 4th element half as likely to be selected as the first.  Entirely up to you to find a behaviour you're happy with.

Also note that here I'm using `replace=True`, because I wanted to select a large number of values to make the plot look better.  If you don't want the same element to be selected twice, use `replace=False`.

Comment: The solution is not working for me. It selects only 0 in my case. How do you do this using np.random.choice?

Comment: Looks like weight is integer. Please make it float.

Comment: @learner: ah, you must be using an ancient version of Python.  You might want to upgrade, lots of people (including me!) no longer always write Python 2-compatible code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### Solving by Re-inventing the Wheel

Here is how you do it from the first principles.

1. `random.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1. This means that the expression `random.random() < x` becomes true less frequently as `x` becomes closer to 0.
2. For each element in the array, say `array[i]`, let us define the odds of the element getting picked as

**`odds_pick(i) = (1 - i / len(array)) * DAMP`.**
  Here, `DAMP` is a number between 0 and 1, which is used to diminish the odds of a number being picked. Thus,

- when i = 0 (the first element), the odds of the element being picked are just = `DAMP`.
- For the last element, it's `DAMP / len(array)`.
- For others, the odds are between these extremes, and they diminish as `i` gets larger.

Finally, to get this appropriate sample, iterate over the array, and check if `random.random() < odds_pick(i)`. If so, pick the element.

Because of how we have defined `odds_pick(i)`, it will become more and more close to 0 as `i` increases, and thus `random.random() < odds_pick(i)` will be less and less true towards the end. Ultimately, this means we end up picking elements more frequently from the front than from the end.

---

### Code:

```
import random
def sample_with_bias(arr, n, damping_factor=.3):
    res = []
    indexes_picked = []
    n_picked = 0
    while n_picked < n:
        for i, x in enumerate(arr):
            odds_pick = damping_factor * (1 - i * 1. / len(arr))
            if i not in indexes_picked and random.random() < odds_pick:
                print(odds_pick)
                n_picked += 1
                indexes_picked.append(i)
                res.append(x)
    return res
```

Note that there are multiple pass over the array to cover the corner case where `n` unique elements could not be sampled in a single pass.

Let's run some experiments:

```
def run_experiment(arr, damping_factor, num_pick=10, num_runs=100):
    all_samples = []
    for i in range(num_runs):
        all_samples.extend(sample_with_bias(arr, num_pick, damping_factor=damping_factor))
    dist = Counter(all_samples)
    dist = sorted(list(dist.items()), key=lambda k: k[0])
    k, v = zip(*dist)
    plt.bar(k, v)
    plt.title("Damping Factor = {0}".format(damping_factor))
    plt.show()
```

and

```
for df in [0.10, 0.50, 0.99]:
    np.random.seed(0)
    a = pd.Series(range(100))
    run_experiment(a, damping_factor=df)
```

---

### Results

- For lots of damping, almost uniform with still a bias for the elements in the beginning:
  [image]
- Let's see what happens when we decrease the damping:

[image]

- With almost no damping, only the elements in the front are picked:

[image]